# Step up regulator with fading input

Tags: led, dimming, step-up

I have an input power source that fades an LED on and off smoothly, from 0 volts to 7.5 volts. I would like to use a 12 volt LED. I have been looking at step up regulators which look suitable for handling the constant input, but ideally I would like the new 12 volt LED to retain the fade on/off effect.

Is there such thing as a step up regulator that will fade to the fixed output voltage?

Comment: Use an NPN on the low side and using voltage-controlled base current with collector amplification to saturation you can get almost the same effect.  Using a transistor rated for 10x actual current for best results.

Comment: LEDs generally operate between 2 and 4 volts. Typically, LEDs in circuits are combined with a current limiting resistor. The combined voltage across both the LED and the current limiting resistor can be greater than the 2-4 volts for an LED. (It is also possible you have multiple LEDs together with a current limiting resistor). Knowing the value of that resistor will help determine how your circuit might be modified to handle 12V. Do  you have a datasheet(s) for your LEDs/devices?

Comment: Simplest solution is alternate the power supply. You may change only one resistor.

Comment: Math Keeps Me Busy - this is for automotive use. Unfortunately I do not have any data on the LED as it is a Mercedes part, but I am not using it for its intended use, hence the input voltage is not 12v

Answer (score 0):

[This is a cheap & dirty solution](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDOB0YwrLAWAnC1bUgIxkgJhrgOyEDMYAHLgGwqEgIlYQK4BQALiLrFVkriBL4%20AiJhABaHEljlMmcoUwkliSgiiFyPBGBIrMsXPlJMwrAO6Dh%20ctYi5d4VgCcuPEZ8z9wgsIUhYVgAlLx9MXDtvUXooAUZGCBwg0KExCPsQKg0k%20jEYpMDWAHNMxwg0rkIC1gB5TMxCXhIqKKbfcxINADMLABMXAHsABwAdAEdsLBAkSCEAUwl5KDAWLCpIUiQqfF1ZEgUKX0xWTB2GjMrG3gFegZGJqfFnrFZdRl0IbZAjKKpcqgAfWygLAgIYiEB%20FBkEwoMBcIAagBjViDQRZHJ5JB2Xg4MDcXzxQRokB0bK%20XRIOjCEh4aYCOgkVgkOwxYzMQgQYLzADOAEteewAIYAO2R81YQA)
Some adjustments on Rb are needed depending on LED strip current and hFE of transistor.

Use an NPN on the low side and using voltage-controlled base current with collector amplification to saturation you can get almost the same effect. Using a transistor rated for 10x actual current for best results.

At half power, the transistor dissipates a lot of power so a heat sink might be needed

Comment: This looks interesting, I'll have a proper look into this. Also that is a nice website :)